# AWS EKS Ingress Controllers, AppMesh VirtualGateway or ALB Ingress

Tags: amazon-eks, ingress-controller, aws-app-mesh

If I am looking at AWS provided Ingress Controllers for my EKS cluster, I have the option of either AWS AppMesh Virtual Gateway [1] or ALB Ingress [2].

What are the rule of thumb of which one to use for which use case? For example, using AppMesh VirtualGateways seems to me is more homogenous with the other mesh topology I have, versus ALB which seems to be annotation based?

I also has the option to do distributed tracing with AppMesh VirtualGateways but not ALB?

1: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/app-mesh/latest/userguide/virtual_gateways.html

2: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/app-mesh-integration-with-aws-alb-ingress-controller/